# How to dump multiple subversion repositories at once on various OSs

Tags: svn, export

How do I make a dump of a number of subversion repositories - with all repositories residing in one folder - on various operating systems (Linux shells, Windows 9x/Vista/XP/Server, etc.)?

I'll post an answer that works on Windows Server 2003 - but maybe there's a more elegant one for that, too.

(Additional background to the question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45519/is-this-note-to-self-appropriate-to-post-on-serverfault).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO_BASE=...
SVNADMIN=...

cd "$REPO_BASE"
for f in *; do
    test -d "$f"  &&  $SVNADMIN dump "$f" >"$f.svn"
done
```

(`test -d` makes sure to dump directories only)

Answer (score 6):

This works on Windows 2003 server and is likely to work on other Windows OS's, too.
It looks for any sub-directories in the specified "repos" directory and tries to run a `svnadmin dump` on each and every one of them. It creates dump files named `(reponame).svn`

dump_repos.bat

```
cd \my\subversion\repos
dir /A:D /B> dirs.tmp
FOR /F %%i IN (dirs.tmp) DO (
 "C:\path\to\subversion\bin\svnadmin.exe" dump %%i > %%i.svn
)
```